# VirtualBox: Bridged Connection Not Working with .ova - High Sierra

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, macos-highsierra

I just bought my first Macbook today (long time Windows user) but I am running into issues loading in the .OVA of Rapid 7's "[Hackazon](https://github.com/rapid7/hackazon)" vulnerable web app into VirtualBox and getting a bridged connection. I know there are lots of these questions that have been posted about networking with VMs, but I have followed all of the suggestions from a dozen forms and nothing seems to work, and I would really like to not regret buying this machine. Here is my setup:

**VirtualBox Settings:**
[Settings Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MsY1.png)

**This is the error that I get when the machine loads**
[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7Gni.png)

**VM showing no network interface**
[ifconfig output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpMeK.png)

Since this is a brand new machine, are there any Mac permissions networking configurations that I should be aware of? Am I missing something dumb? This generally worked when I used VMs in the past.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Huh--strange! So it turns out that it was something with that particular .ova file. I just downloaded Ubuntu and it was able to bridge no problem. I guess that's something that I need to report to Rapid7.